# Wrap long text in table row in mobile view

Tags: html, css

I have a table which takes a different view in mobile with each row's td displayed as column in mobile view. I have a long text in one td which I want to wrap in mobile. (In desktop, the width of the column expands so its fine)

I have tried every possible method - word wrap, word break, adjusting width, white space etc. but nothing is working.

Below is the code.

```css
.test-table .table {
  width: 50%;
}

@media all and (max-width: 500px){
        
  .test-table .table {
    width: 85%;    
  }

  .table  thead {
    display: none;
  }
    
  .test-table .table tr {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
  }

  .test-table table td::before {
    content: attr(col);
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-right: 20px;
    width: 40vw;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: top
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="test-table">
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th >Name</th>
        <th >Designation</th>
        <th >Address</th>
        <th >Email</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td col="Name">Mark</td>
        <td col="Designation">ABC</td>
        <td col="Address">Markmarkmarkmarkamarkmarkmark</td>
        <td col="Email">mark@g.com</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

I want the address to wrap without distorting the alignment. How can I fix this?

Comment: What's your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

```css
.test-table .table {
        width: 50%

    }

@media all and (max-width: 500px){

        .test-table .table {
                width: 85%

        }

        .table  thead {
            display: none;
            }

        .test-table .table tr {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            margin-bottom: 5px;

            }

        .test-table table th {
            content: attr(col);
            font-weight: bold;
            padding-right: 20px;
            width: 40vw;
            display:inline-block;
            vertical-align: top

            }
        .test-table table td {
            word-break : break-all;
            width: 40vw;
            text-align: center;
            }
    }
```

```html
<div class="test-table">
        <table class="table">
            <tbody>
                <tr><th >Name</th>
                <td col="Name">Mark</td></tr>
                <tr><th >Designation</th>
                <td col="Designation">ABC</td></tr>
                <tr><th >Address</th>
                <td col="Address">Markmarkmarkmarkamarkmarkmark</td></tr>
                <tr><th >Email</th>
                <td col="Email">mark@g.com</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
      </table>
      </div>
```

I changed your html table, th tag.